# compass: how to get the position of a autogenerated sprite

Tags: sass, compass-sass

i'm loading and generating my sprite with:

```
@import "map/*.png";
@include all-map-sprites;
```

then i'm trying to get the position using the sprite-position method:

```
background-position: sprite-position($map, icon-name);
```

this rises following error:

**Undefined variable: "$map".**

is there any automagicly assigned variable like $map or $map-sprite?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@import "map/*.png";
@include all-map-sprites;

$map: sprite-map("map/*.png");
background-position: sprite-position($map, icon-name);
```

@TomRoggero has suggested a shorter variant:

```
@import "map/*.png";
@include all-map-sprites;

background-position: sprite-position($map-sprites, icon-name);
```

Comment: Wrong answer. You should use `background-position: sprite-position($map-sprites, name)` instead of `$map` and you don't need to do the `$map` definition

Comment: Well, the answer isn't wrong: it gets the job done as well as your variant does. Your variant is just one line shorter and slightly quicker. I've added your suggestion to the answer.